# Get a random result from two sub arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How can I take two sub arrays then randomly get two choices from each one?

This is a little hard to explain so I will share the code and a codepen link below (please see the second function getSelection() as this is where my problem lies):

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/ryan_pixelers/pen/KgLKOr)

**Javascript:**

```
(function(){


/*
 * Create a function to display all positions
 */
function createPositions() {

    // the array of positions
    var positions = [
        "Missionary",
        "Doggy Style",
        "Sixty-nine",
        "Girl on top",
        "Back door",
        "Golden shower",
        "BDSM",
        "Blow job"
    ];

    // get hold of the list container on the page
    var listContainer = document.getElementById('positions');

    // loop through all the positions and place each one in an li element 
    for(var i = 0, n = positions.length; i < n; i++) {

        // create an li element
        var listElement = document.createElement("button");

        var listValue = listElement.setAttribute("value", "position-" + [i]);

        // create the text to be placed in the element
        var listContent = document.createTextNode(positions[i]);

        // append the text to the li 
        listElement.appendChild(listContent);

        // append the li to the ul 
        listContainer.appendChild(listElement);
    }
}

// call function 
createPositions();

/*
 * Create a function that gets the selections 
 * from the user
 */
function getSelection() {

    // create an empty array
    var selections = [];
    var femaleSelections = [];
    var maleSelections = [];

    // get the main container of the page
    var container = document.getElementById("main-container");

    // start out with a default class
    container.className = "female";

    // store the choices as an array
    var choices = document.querySelectorAll('button');  

    // get the length of the choices so we can loop over all of them                
    var choicesLength = choices.length;

    // start loop 
    for(var i = 0; i < choicesLength; i++) {
        // for each element in the array, add an event listener to the
        // button which is clicked
        choices[i].addEventListener("click", function(){

            // the position, as in "sexual" position, is the value of the 
            // current element / button
            var position = this.getAttribute("value");

            // push that position into the selections array
            // selections.push(position);

            // for debugging - TODO: delete this:
            // console.log(selections);


            // First get the female selections
            if(femaleSelections.length < 2) {

                // push them into the femaleSections array
                femaleSelections.push(position);

                // DEBUG: 
                console.log(femaleSelections);

                // change the classname to male once female selections reach 2
                if(femaleSelections.length == 2) {
                    container.className = "male";
                    selections.push(femaleSelections);
                }
            }

            // now get male selections
            else if(maleSelections.length < 2) {

                // push them into the maleSelections array
                maleSelections.push(position);

                // DEBUG: 
                console.log(maleSelections);

                // change the classname to results once the male sections reach 2
                // and disable all the buttons so no more selections can be made
                if(maleSelections.length == 2) {
                    container.className = "results";
                    selections.push(maleSelections);


                    var randomSelectionF = Math.floor(Math.random() * selections.length);
                    var randomSelectionM = Math.floor(Math.random() * selections.length);

                    var decision = "F: " + selections[randomSelectionF] + " " + "M: " + selections[randomSelectionM];

                    var answerElement = document.getElementById("chosenPositions");

                    answerElement.innerHTML = "Your positions are: " + decision + "!";

                    // disable all the buttons so no more selections can be made
                    choices.forEach(function(element){
                        element.disabled = true;
                    })  ;

                }
            }

        });

    }       

}

// call the function
getSelection();


})();
```

This is still very much a work in progress. Please try clicking on a few selections to see the final result. The idea is that the web page gives back two positions (I will expand on this later to allow the user to choose the number of positions) from each selection, ie one selection from partner 1 and one selection from partner 2.

Hope this all makes sense.

Thanks for your help.

P.S NO JQUERY!!

Comment: So, basically, it's sex dice. At any rate, just generate a random number between `0` and `array.length` and use that.

Comment: do you want a random item from the intersected selections from both arrays?

Comment: I give you +1 so you don't feel so sad and lonely?

Comment: I have no idea what your question is here! `please see the second function getSelection() as this is where my problem lies` - but you've not told us what the problem is!

Comment: @Jamiec ahh yes I have "Currently, I have the selections I want but when I try to randomly select one choice from each array, it gives me all choices and sometimes gives me the exact same choice!" That's the problem

Comment: Yes, thats vaguely a combination of words which make a semi-coherent sentence, but it doesnt really tell me what your problem is. Show us an [mcve] demonstrating the problem (And no, that does not mean a huge code dump in codepen).

Comment: @RyanMc please delete the long, irrelevant introduction. It's really not necessary. Just describe your problem.

Comment: You are trying to create a cool sex machine but still not using the cool JQuery. Pity that !

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a total mess. When clicking your elements you append to either `femaleSelection` or `maleSelection`

```
femaleSelections.push(position); 
//or
maleSelections.push(position);
```

And you *also* push that array into another array *for every click*

```
selections.push(femaleSelections);
```

So now `selections` is an array of arrays - note that your commented code indicates you had this somewhat right at some point:

```
// push that position into the selections array
// selections.push(position);
```

That would be a better way to do it, albeit you may like to distinguish between what selections the female made from the male.

---

That will give you a start I hope, I am not sure where you're trying to go from there (As I commented the question is unclear).

Perhaps you want to make a random selection from the intersection of the male & female selections - which would be fine but I'm not writing the code if I've made an incorrect assumption. You also need to consider the case where there is no intersection.

---

According to your comment, the only part you have wrong is this:

```
var randomSelectionF = Math.floor(Math.random() * selections.length);
var randomSelectionM = Math.floor(Math.random() * selections.length);

var decision = "F: " + selections[randomSelectionF] + " " + "M: " + selections[randomSelectionM];
```

As you're not using your male and female arrays but instead are using the array of arrays (`selections` that really has no purpose elsewhere.

```
var randomSelectionF = Math.floor(Math.random() * femaleSelections.length);
var randomSelectionM = Math.floor(Math.random() * maleSelections.length);

var decision = "F: " + femaleSelections[randomSelectionF] + " " + "M: " + selections[maleSelections];
```

Comment: If you clarify what exactly you're trying to do I'll happily update my answer.

Comment: So basically, the female makes 2 selections, they're stored in an array, then the male does the same thing. Now we have 4 selections. Finally I want to choose one option from both of male and female, and then show them on the screen. So basically the web page would throw back to you something like "Your positions are **missionary** and **doggy style**" LOL

Comment: @RyanMc ah in which case your answer is easy. Check update in about 2 minutes